# How to upload files on openfire server through Strophe XMPP library

Tags: file-upload, xmpp, strophe

I am developing a xmpp chat client, and i want to add functionality of sending files like zip, pdf, docx, ppt, images etc. I research on net about it and come to know that XEP-0047(In-band-bytestream) is good to send files in base-64 form, and i am able to send and receive base 64 data, but my question is- I can convert a file to base 64, but after receiving it, how can I retrieve it back in its original form?

And if not, then is there any such thing is possible by Strophe that we can upload  file(to send) to the server and then send the corresponding link to receiver so that he can download it, if yes then how to upload and download file using Stophe?

Comment: I am also finding the same implementation. Do you find solution? please also help me.